# Libgdx Texture is flickering when being moved

Tags: java, android, libgdx, render, flicker

I have an image that I want to move to the right. To do this I increase its `x` position by `200f*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` every time render is called. I've read other posts where people had similar problems but were they were not multiplying by `delta` or `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`. Because I obviously do this why is my image flickering/vibrating when its moving???

My code:

```
public class gm extends Game{
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    float x = 0;     

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");  
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
        //x += 200f*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        cam.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, x += 100f*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 0);      
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your texture filter is Nearest/Nearest (which is the default) then whenever you draw something, you need to round the position off to the nearest integer so the pixels of the texture won't have rounding issues that cause flickering. So in your case do `x += 100f*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();` on its own line. Then do `batch.draw(img, Math.round(x), 0);`

Comment: unfortunately this still creates a jitter when moving my image

Comment: I cant understand why at certain times there's a random back movement